# Can I build app with Vue-CLI then include it in a current PHP application?

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm currently building a Vue front end for a current PHP application page. I'm curious if I can build the view in Vue-CLI first then include it in the PHP application? If so, how could I accomplish this?

I currently have most of the view done but I'm including a Vue CDN link and just doing the work in page. Which can pile up pretty fast! I would also be able to work faster working through Vue-CLI.

The reason I need to also include this into a PHP page is because of the user session throughout the app. Need to know the user currently logged in. I already have that variable being used, so no issues there. In case anyone was curious as to why PHP.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It's much much easier if you are using a REST api

Comment: Its not my application or I would :( I am using axios within the vue component for data though. Only using user session from the PHP application

Comment: @zeus - I would say that if you did a production build of your Vue application which should compile all of the single file components down to just one file via WebPack that you should be able to create basically an Index page in your PHP app, and drop all of the Vue SPA references there. Might have to adjust folder paths or something to a public folder for the rest of the assets also.

Comment: Just bundle everything together with webpack and use the bundle in your php application? You can use the assets plugin for webpack and parse the assets.json file to have cache-busting.